# stanford-nlp naive bayes classifier training

Tags: stanford-nlp, naivebayes

as part of understanding the stanford nlp api for classification, i am training the naive bayes classifier on a very simple training set (3 labels => ['happy','sad','neutral']). This training data set is

```
happy   happy
happy   glad
sad gloomy
neutral fine
```

this is part of the output from training the classifier (before the error)

```
numDatumsPerLabel: {happy=2.0, sad=1.0, neutral=1.0}
numLabels: 3 [happy, sad, neutral]
numFeatures (Phi(X) types): 4 [1-SW-happy, 1-SW-glad, 1-SW-gloomy, 1-SW-fine]
```

I get the an array index out of bounds error. I have attached the stack trace. I am unable to find the problem.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at edu.stanford.nlp.classify.NaiveBayesClassifierFactory.trainWeightsJL(NaiveBayesClassifierFactory.java:171)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.classify.NaiveBayesClassifierFactory.trainWeights(NaiveBayesClassifierFactory.java:146)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.classify.NaiveBayesClassifierFactory.trainClassifier(NaiveBayesClassifierFactory.java:84)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.classify.NaiveBayesClassifierFactory.trainClassifier(NaiveBayesClassifierFactory.java:352)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier.makeClassifier(ColumnDataClassifier.java:1458)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier.trainClassifier(ColumnDataClassifier.java:2091)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.classify.demo.ClassifierDemo.main(ClassifierDemo.java:35)
```

As part of obtaining the weights in

```
 private NBWeights trainWeightsJL(int[][] data, int[] labels, int numFeatures, int numClasses) {
    int[] numValues = numberValues(data, numFeatures);
    double[] priors = new double[numClasses];
    double[][][] weights = new double[numClasses][numFeatures][];
    //init weights array
    for (int cl = 0; cl < numClasses; cl++) {
      for (int fno = 0; fno < numFeatures; fno++) {
        weights[cl][fno] = new double[numValues[fno]];
//        weights[cl][fno] = new double[numFeatures];
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      priors[labels[i]]++;
      for (int fno = 0; fno < numFeatures; fno++) {
        weights[labels[i]][fno][data[i][fno]]++;
      }
    }
    for (int cl = 0; cl < numClasses; cl++) {
      for (int fno = 0; fno < numFeatures; fno++) {
        for (int val = 0; val < numValues[fno]; val++) {
          weights[cl][fno][val] = Math.log((weights[cl][fno][val] + alphaFeature) / (priors[cl] + alphaFeature * numValues[fno]));
        }
      }
      priors[cl] = Math.log((priors[cl] + alphaClass) / (data.length + alphaClass * numClasses));
    }
    return new NBWeights(priors, weights);
  }
```

i am unable to understand what

```
int[] numValues = numberValues(data, numFeatures);
```

means. The error is from the line

```
weights[labels[i]][fno][data[i][fno]]++;
```

I would have thought weights is a 2d array to keep track of feature (fno) occurences for different classes(labels). Not sure why the third dimension is needed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have any problem building a classifier with your training data set.  What are the settings in your properties file.  What command are you issuing to run this?

Comment: useClassFeature=false
1.useSplitWords=true
1.splitWordsWithPTBTokenizer=true


# loadClassifier=projects/core/src/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/mood.classifier

printClassifier=HighWeight
printClassifierParam=20
justify=true
displayedColumn=-1
lowercase=true
csvInput=false

useNB=true
useClass=true
sigma=1.0
prior=false


# Training input

trainFile=projects/core/src/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/mood3.train
testFile=projects/core/src/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/mood3.test

# for the pipeline
annotators=cdc

Comment: i am running the /edu/stanford/nlp/classify/demo/ClassifierDemo.java. i have commented line 1457 of ColumnDataClassifier.java and instead added       lc = new NaiveBayesClassifierFactory<String,String>().trainClassifier(train);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not having any issues with these properties:

```
#
# Features
#
useClassFeature=true
1.useNGrams=true
1.usePrefixSuffixNGrams=true
1.maxNGramLeng=4
1.minNGramLeng=1
1.binnedLengths=10,20,30
#
# Printing
#
# printClassifier=HighWeight
printClassifierParam=200
#
# Mapping
#
goldAnswerColumn=0
displayedColumn=1
#
# Optimization
#
intern=true
sigma=3
useQN=true
QNsize=15
tolerance=1e-4
useNB=true
useClass=true
#
# Training input
#
trainFile=simple-classifier-training-set.txt
serializeTo=model.txt
```

And running this command:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier -prop example.prop
```